# Setup build fastlane with Jenkins for iOS

Tags: ios, jenkins, fastlane

I'm newbie in setup jenkins on macos

I've already installed Jenkins, Fastlane. But after building on Jenkins. It return this issue 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem fastlane (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)

I set up the current version of ruby that is 2.4.1. But it's always get version 2.3.0.

Have you any ideas for this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
rvm list
```

Use the rvm which you want to use from the list (example 2.4.1)

```
rvm use 2.4.1
```

You can check which version of ruby is being used

```
which ruby
```

In Jenkins job, you can set the version of ruby  `Run the build in a RVM-managed environment`